# What is the difference between serial and dun bluetooth service?

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I create an android simple bluetooth terminal application for communication with my old java cellphone Sony Ericsson K700.I discover services from android and find this uuid : 1101(serial service) , 1103(DUN) .I test it with AT coomands at reply ok both of them.What is the difference between serial and dun bluetooth service? Can i connect to the internet from android using my old cellphone as modem?

Answer (score 0):

DUN is dial-up networking and may get you online if you know the correct connect string. When I'd tether my old T-Mobile phone, I used something like `at+cgdcont=1,"IP","epc.tmobile.com"`. The serial service is generally for communication to an app on the phone.